# Accessing static variable from a friend function

Tags: c++, function, static, friend, var

```
class Base
{
private:
    static int num; 
public:
    friend void setnum(Base obj); 
};

void setnum(Base obj)
{
    obj.num=4;  /* Error */
}
```

A friend function is supposed to have access to all the private data of a class. what am i missing here? I cant seem to access the the static variable from the friend function.

> Error from codepad-->  In function
>   `setnum(Base)': undefined reference to`
>   Base::num'
>
> Error from visual studio--> error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static int Base::num"

Comment: The class was present in the cpp file. it was just a basic code bit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only declared the static variable `num`. You must to define it:

```
class Base
{
private:
    static int num; 
public:
    friend void setvals(Base obj); 
};

// This must be in a .cpp
int Base::num;

void setvals(Base obj)
{
    obj.num=4;
}
```

This code works.

**Edit:**

Actually you can implement the `setvals()` function  as follows:

```
void setvals()
{
    Base::num=4;
}
```

And at your Base class:

```
friend void setvals();
```

Because `num` is static.

Comment: at the first quick glance i found this to be more informative

Answer (score 4):

Your free function is called `setvals`, but the `Base`'s friend function is called `setnum`...

Besides you'll have to actually define the static variable, not just declare it.

Put:

```
int Base::num;
```

in a source file.

Comment: Editing within 5 minutes is cheating. :)  But you now have both errors, so I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: no, don't. You probably got there first. I didn't your answer, was editing mine.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you copied mine or any other answer.  And I frequently edit within 5 minutes. :)  'Sides, I got a disciplined badge out of it.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: anyway I think you should undelete your answer: it was correct, and according to the votes you probably posted it before I could finish editing mine. -- Oh, well, congrats for your badge then `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Static variables don't belong to any particular instance of a class. Instead you may access them with a class name as `Base::num` to improve readability. Also, your friend function definition has a different signature than the one you declared.

Comment: You *can* access them as obj.num.

Comment: You can access but that gives impression to the programmer/reader that they belong to that particular instance. So, to improve readability you should access them with class name.

Comment: While it may be more readable that way (I don't think it always is), it is still wrong that you "have to access them with a class name".

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Corrected my sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Different friends:

```
friend void setnum(Base obj); 
         //    ^^^  Not the same as vals!
       void setvals(Base obj)
```

Comment: it was a typing error when i was pasting the code bit here i tried to change the function name.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it's not enough to declare a static variable in the .h; you must also define it explicitly in a .cpp. You must add in the .cpp of the implementation

```
int Base::num;
```

What you got was a linker error because of this missing variable definition.